# Right-align text and image stack in a responsive environment

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, media-queries

I am trying to stack a logo with the right-aligned site title and tagline in a full-width header that has a background image. This would be relatively simple to do in an html module, but I would like to do it in a header module if possible (so the client can change the background image easily). The problem is that the logo does not remain right-aligned with the title and tagline but moves horizontally as the window size and zoom levels change.  I've attached a two images, labelled `desired` and `mis-aligned` showing the problem.

I've been trying to do this with the `::before` pseudo class:
Is it possible stack a logo, site title, and site tagline and have them all right align? I am trying to stack a logo with the right-aligned site title and tagline in a full-width header that has a background image. The problem is that the logo does not remain right-aligned with the title and tagline but moves horizontally as the window size and zoom levels change.

I've been trying to do this with the `::before` pseudo class:

```
.site-title::before {    
    content: "";
    background: url("http://www.acchs.edu/2014b/wp-content/uploads/ACCHS_Transparent-150x146.png")     
    no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    right: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enough info to help here. A link would be good.

Comment: Sorry.  The link is acchs.edu/2014b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see the point of using `::before` for this, as you could just put the logo in the HTML as an image above the `h1`. Anyhow, you can easily do this with :befre by giving the h1 `position: relative` so that the ::before content is positioned relative to the h1.Then you just adjust the logo's positioning. E.g.

```
h1 {
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: 0; 
    padding-top: 130px;
}
.site-title::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("http://www.acchs.edu/2014b/wp-content/uploads/ACCHS_Transparent-150x146.png") no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: That seemed like a good approach and it works well on a phone. On larger screens, however, it causes the logo and title to overlap. Also, I'm using ::before because this is a WordPress site and I don't want to hard-code the logo into the page template.

Comment: It works for me on desktop, but you need to make sure you remove the original styles on the generated content, such as `margin-top: 90px;`.

Comment: I entered the code you supplied (adding only a class of .site-title to the H1, so it doesn't affect all H1) and commented out my previous code, but I'm  still missing something. On screen widths above 1200, the logo floats right of the text. At 340 and below, the logo overlaps the text. I appreciate your help; any further info would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you left those styles in there, unless I'm missing something, but we seem to be back to square one each time.

Comment: Sorry, when you you said "remove the original styles on the generated content, such as 'margin-top: 50px;' I thought you meant I should remove (comment out) the previous .site-title and ::before content and leave in only the code you had supplied.  I've now left everything in the stylesheet except the original 'margin-top: 50px;'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was suggesting you make sure all the styles I gave above are in there, and remove any conflicting styles that were in there. If you could add in the code above, I can then see what's causing it not to work.

Comment: I have all of your code in and I believe I've deleted or commented out everything I had that conflicted.  I'm not sure if my code of `float: right;` and `text-align: right;` for the site-title.h1 conflicts with any of your code.

Comment: OK, you've made a slight mistake. Instead of `.site-title h1`, you should have `h1.site-title`.

Comment: Made the change and now it looks lovely on a full-width browser. But when the screen goes below the breakpoint (on a phone), the logo overlaps the site title. Tried adding `<br />` in unicode escaped characters as the content, but no joy.

Comment: On line 1645 of your style sheet you have a media query that resets the padding on the `h1`. Just remove that line and all should be well.

Comment: Bingo!  That was it.  Thanks so much for your perseverance and knowledge-sharing.